# VS Code Python debugger - parameter values during return

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

I am using VS code's Python debugger to monitor function returns.

```
Python: 3.7.3
VS Code:  1.51.0
Python Extension: v2020.11.371526539
MACOS: 10.15.7 (19H2)
```

I can inspect the variables before they are returned, and they are correct, but after the return, they assume previously held values - like they never got overwritten by the return statement.

```
def align_bb(self, bbs2)
    ...
    # the variables are correct  at this point 
    return update_obj, new_obj, stale_obj

#but they change by the time they come back from the function
update_obj, new_obj, stale_obj = trk.align_bb(bbs2)
```

Parameter values inside the function

```
update_obj, new_obj, stale_obj
([], [[...], [...], [...]], [0])
special variables
function variables
0:[]
1:[[10, 20, 80, 100], [80, 110, 90, 110], [80, 100, 10, 40]]
2:[0]
len():3
```

Parameter values after the return statement:

```
update_obj, new_obj, stale_obj
([], [[...]], [])
special variables
function variables
0:[]
1:[[35, 65, 35, 65]]
2:[]
len():3
```

If I run the code outside the debugger, the return values remain consistent.  I have restarted VS code, and my computer. I have also reverted the python extension and uninstalled it but I get the same weird values every time.  I am definitely looking at the values after the function return, not before.

Comment: Does your code do the wrong thing, or is it just a debugger display problem?

Comment: it seems to be limited to the debugger.  If I run `python tracker.py` the returns are correct.  I was also getting those values in the debug console

Answer (score 0):

I had a breakpoint at the return line in the function and a breakpoint at the function call/assignment after the return.

```
    def align_bb(self, bbs2)
    ...
    # the variables are correct  at this point 
    return update_obj, new_obj, stale_obj # I had a breakpoint here

update_obj, new_obj, stale_obj = trk.align_bb(bbs2) # and a breakpoint here
assert update_obj == []
#moving the breakpoint to the next line of execution fixed the issue.
```

Moving the latter breakpoint fixes the issue.  It is repeatable - If I put the breakpoint back, the error occurs.

I would like to know why it happened so I am leaving the question unresolved for now.